# Make 'Enter' key default to a certain button in a Django crispy form?

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I have a form that subclasses PhoneNumberForm from the django-two-factor-auth-library. It renders a text box in which to enter phone number, and a Back button and Next button beneath it. The issue is that when the form is filled out and the user hits the 'Enter' key on their keyboard, the Back button is triggered.

[image]

I have tried swapping the two buttons, which gives me the behavior I want, but not the correct layout. But I do see that whichever button is defined first in FormActions gets selected on hitting Enter.

I have  also tried adding an 'autofocus' field to my Next button, but that only focuses on the button when the page loads, not after I've switched focus to the text box and typed in a number.

I would like to maintain the order I currently have (Back button on the left, Next on the right), but have the Enter key trigger the Next button. How do I do this?

```
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms import layout as crispy
from crispy_forms import bootstrap as twbscrispy


def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(PhoneNumberForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.helper = FormHelper()
    self.helper.form_class = 'form form-horizontal'
    self.helper.label_class = 'col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-2'
    self.helper.field_class = 'col-sm-9 col-md-8 col-lg-6'
    self.helper.layout = crispy.Layout(
        crispy.Fieldset(
            '',
            'number'
        ),
        twbscrispy.FormActions(


            twbscrispy.StrictButton(
                _('Back'),
                css_class='btn-default',
                type='submit',
                value='method',
                name='wizard_goto_step',
            ),



            twbscrispy.StrictButton(
                _('Next'),
                css_class='btn-primary',
                type='submit',
            )



        )
    )
```

Comment: Should the clicking the back button submit the form?

Comment: For form wizard's wizard_goto_step to work, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You browser is using <Enter> for the first button where **type** = "**submit**" in the form.

If you change your "Back" button **type** to "**button**", then your "Next" button will be the first submit button in your form, and <Enter> will activate it.

You can still get your "Back" button to submit your form, if you use an "onclick" attribute, and give your form an "id" attribute.

e.g.

```
# ...
self.helper = FormHelper()
self.helper.form_id = 'wizard_form_id'
# ...
twbscrispy.StrictButton(
    _('Back'),
    css_class='btn-default',
    type='button',
    value='method',
    name='wizard_goto_step',
    onclick="document.getElementById('wizard_form_id').submit();",
),
twbscrispy.StrictButton(
    _('Next'),
    css_class='btn-primary',
    type='submit',
)
```

Comment: So the way that form wizard is working, wizard_goto_step will not be triggered unless this form data is submitted, which is why I need the back button to also be a 'submit'. Is there a way that I can make it type 'button' but still have it submit (without having to use js)?

Comment: A little JS, just an "onclick" attribute, hopefully not too much. I updated my answer.